# Can't import gnupg keys due to ascii conversion?

Tags: macos, utf-8, ascii, gnupg

I have a problem importing my gpg keys onto my macbook pro. This is the output:

```
pg: conversion from `utf-8' to `US-ASCII' failed: Illegal byte sequence
gpg: key 5AE36741: public key "Micha\xc5\x82 Adamczyk <michal.anks@gmail.com>" imported
```

After that key is imported but unusable by i.e. enigmail.
Any ideas on how can i fix this?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I had a similar problem and solved it by adding `charset utf-8` to `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`.

Comment: That should be the default.

Comment: @foolip So, how will this interact with other people reading my key? Will they have to turn on UTF-8 as well?

Comment: @Dorian no, it's just some error on the ASCII conversion on macOS when displaying as text. On Debian it displayed the same key correctly, without setting the charset encoding.